# Cabal installing HsOpenSSL w/ 64-bit OpenSSL libs on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, haskell, openssl

I have a haskell project that I'm trying to build on Windows 2008 64-bit. One of the dependencies is `HsOpenSSL` (not be to confused w/ hopenssl). Per the GHC docs, in order for this install to go smoothly one must install a binary distribution of openssl from here: http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html and link during the cabal install process like this:

```
cabal install HsOpenSSL --extra-include-dirs="c:/OpenSSL-Win32/include" --extra-lib-dirs="c:/OpenSSL-Win32"
```

Now the problem arises when I attempt to install the 64-bit binary distribution and install HsOpenSSL w/ it.

```
 cabal install HsOpenSSL --extra-include-dirs="c:/OpenSSL-Win64/include" --extra-lib-dirs="c:/OpenSSL-Win64"
```

This still throws the error of:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring HsOpenSSL-0.10.3.5...
cabal.exe: Missing dependencies on foreign libraries:
* Missing C libraries: eay32, ssl32
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system packages that
provide these libraries (you may need the "-dev" versions). If the libraries
are already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the
flags --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where they are.
Failed to install HsOpenSSL-0.10.3.5
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
HsOpenSSL-0.10.3.5 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

After inspecting the directories (OpenSSL-Win32 and OpenSSL-Win64) the directories are apparently the exact same with one small difference. There is no MinGW folder in `OpenSSL-Win64/libs/`, but there is one in `OpenSSL-Win32/libs/`. After removing this directory from the `OpenSSL-Win32` install directory, HsOpenSSL still installs fine when linked w/ the 32-bit libs. So I don't think that difference seems to matter. All that to ask, **Is HsOpenSSL compatible with openssl's 64-bit libs?** Is there anything obviously wrong about what I'm doing?

I'm using Cygwin, cabal 1.18.0.2, ghc 7.6.3, openSSL version 1.0.1e

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit GHC?

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov The Haskell Platform for Windows only has one installer and does not give arch. information. But the install path into Program Files (x86) leads me to believe that it is 32-bit

Comment: There is no native 64-bit Haskell Platform installer at the moment (mea culpa). But there is a 64-bit GHC for Windows: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_6_1#windows64 You need a 64-bit GHC if you want to link with 64-bit libraries.

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov thanks! I've scrapped the haskell platform and now have standalone versions of cabal and ghc (64-bit). The problem is now that in order to build my project I'm missing a lot of stuff the Haskell platform would've given ootb. Like `cabal.exe: the program ar is required but could not be found`

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov how much work would it be to port the Haskell Platform currently to a 64-bit version? I wouldn't mind getting involved. I kind of need it anyways.

Comment: Try following the steps here: https://github.com/haskell/haskell-platform/blob/master/src/win32/README That's the process I use for producing an installer. If you succeed, drop me a note or do a pull request.

Comment: Regarding missing `ar`, you probably need to add `$GHC_DIR/mingw/bin` to `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

It's four years later, but I just encountered the same problem so I guess its still relevant.
I solved it by downloading the latest Win64OpenSSL binaries, and manually cloning the HsOpenSSL repo at https://github.com/vshabanov/HsOpenSSL.
Then I opened the HsOpenSSL.cabal file and changed line 94 from

```
Extra-Libraries: eay32 ssl
```

to:

```
Extra-Libraries: libeay32 ssleay32
```

Finally, open cmd and make the repo your current directory. Then use `cabal configure --extra-include-dirs="c:/OpenSSL-Win64/include" --extra-lib-dirs="c:/OpenSSL-Win64/lib"` and `cabal install` to install the library.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me with stack. Still getting "missing C libraries". Also tried with the 32-bit version of OpenSSL.